# Generalization of Binary Decomposition to Polynomials?

Tags: ds.algorithms, polynomials

Given an integer $x\in\mathbb{Z}$, we can write its binary decomposition (and more generally base $B$ for $B\in\mathbb{Z}$, $B>1$) as

$$x = \sum_{i=0} x_i B^i,$$

where $x_i \in \mathbb{Z}/B\mathbb{Z}$.
One can compute this decomposition recursively via setting $x_{0} = x\bmod B$, and the setting

$$x = \frac{x - x_0}{B}\bmod B,$$
setting $x_1 = x\bmod B$, and repeating until $x = 0$.

These decompositions are often quite useful in computation.
Trivial examples are things like defining arithmetic for $\mathbb{Z}$ in terms of arithmetic for $\mathbb{Z}/B\mathbb{Z}$ (commonly seen for $b = 2^{32}$ and $2^{64}$).
Slightly less trivial (though quite memorable once you have seen it once) examples are things like the "square and multiply" algorithm --- for $G$ a group, one can compute $G\times\mathbb{Z}\ni (g,x)\mapsto g^x$ by writing $g^x := \prod_{i : x_i = 1} g^{2^i}$, reducing a naively $O(|x|)$ computation to $O(\log |x|)$ group operations.

I am curious about the extension of this decomposition to other settings.
For example, It appears you get an analogous construction for $f(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$, namely decomposing
$$
f(x) = \sum_i f_i(x) g(x)^i
$$
where $f_i(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]/(g(x))$, via essentially the same recursive formula.

1. Does this general decomposition have a name?
2. Does it have other non-obvious applications to computation? For the square-and-multiply algorithm, one can phrase it as an efficient way to compute $\mathbb{Z}$-actions on sets (among other things, to compute in abelian groups). The extension would give efficient ways to compute $\mathbb{Z}[x]$-actions --- do these arise anywhere?